# Using a placeholder as indices parameter in tf.one_hot method

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm learning Tensorflow.

I have found this code, that I don't understand:

```
# Next, we define the placeholder for our label:
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None, None])

#convert the label to one hot
y_one_hot = tf.one_hot(y, depth=num_classes)
```

If `y` is placeholder is empty, so it has not sense to use it in `tf.one_hot`'s indices parameter.

Why are they using a placeholder as a parameter in `tf.one_hot`?

The only explanation I can think of is that `y` is like a pointer, and when I use `y_one_hot` it will filled with the data that will contain `y`. But they don't "insert" any data into `y` variable.

By the way, the full code of my example is [here](https://github.com/sudharsan13296/Hands-On-Meta-Learning-With-Python/blob/master/03.%20Prototypical%20Networks%20and%20its%20Variants/3.3%20Omniglot%20Character%20set%20classification%20using%20Prototypical%20Network.ipynb).

Comment: `y` is not "empty", it is a placeholder tensor with two dimensions, each with an unspecified size. `y_one_hot` will be the one-hot encoded version of `y`, for whatever value `y` takes later. In the training loop, the `feed_dict` includes `y:labels`, which means `y` will take the value of the NumPy array `labels` in that iteration.

Comment: Thanks @jdehesa. I'm trying to migrate that code to Tensorflow 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

I think as you know, tensorflow breaks down everything to data and operations. Those are used to form a computation graph.

If you look down to the computation graph in full code `y_hot_one` used in `loss` function. After that, after initialize the session and run the three functions feeding data to the graph. `feed_dict` is where insert the data to the computation graph and data flows through the graph to **loss function** and to `y_one_hot`.

```
_, loss_, accuracy_ = sess.run([train, loss, accuracy], feed_dict={support_set: support, query_set: query, y:labels})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm going to migrate this code to Tensorflow 2.x and it is a challenge for me.